# URL rewriting - Prestashop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, prestashop

I have a problem with a Prestashop running on a webserver with NGINX.
I cannot get the Webservice working correctly... the webservice itselfs works, and is tested ok.
But when I try to access the `domain.com/api/`, I get a redirect error.
It should pass on the request to this url: `/webservice/dispatcher.php`

The htaccess file contains these lines, but I think there is a problem here.

```
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this fixed ?

Comment: Unless you include your current nginx config to your question, I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: I just have access to a Plesk Server running the site... I am not sure where to find this information ?

Comment: I have no idea. I think it is a question to your hosting support rather then SO community.

Comment: "with NGINX" - Where does Nginx fit into this? `.htaccess` is obviously part of Apache. What "redirect error" are you getting exactly? There are no (external) "redirects" in the code you posted? Where is the `.htaccess` file located? What other directives do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution...
Instead of these 3 lines, I got it working with these 2 lines.:

```
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api(?:/(.*))?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Curious though, the net result of the 3 lines should be the same (just a little less efficient), unless... you have a `RewriteBase` directive set to something other than the root, or there is some other conflict with existing directives?